# $scope.watch ('$scope',.. in Angular

Tags: angularjs, scope, watch

I want to check for fun every changes in the scope and I've tried the following:

```
$scope.$watch('$scope', function(newValue) {
    console.log ("$scope's NewValue", newValue);
}, true);
```

I get the log message:

```
$scope's NewValue undefined
```

Is that, what am trying, is possible anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really suggest you to not do this. It will have a high cost in your application.

```
$scope.$watch(function() { // First function must return the object that you want to watch.
    return $scope;      
},
function(newValue, oldValue) { // This is a callback executed everytime your $scope will change
    console.log("$scope's NewValue : ", newValue);   // You should rather use $log if you want to unit test your code one day
},
true   // Needed to tell angular to watch deeply inside $scope (every sub item).
);
```

Comment: Unbelivable, what Angular does everything in background! Thank you, it works with great delays and some errors: `Error: [ng:cpws] Can't copy! Making copies of Window or Scope instances is not supported.`

Comment: @Vienna There is nothing magic here. Everytime angular detects something has change, he will trigger all of the watches you applied. So, use $watch with caution, or, avoid it